# Where to look for team mates?

Tags: project-management

Where is a good place to look for people interested in creating games online? I'll be using XNA.

I'm going to start the project later this week, but I'm definitely commited to it. I'd like to find people who won't hit it and quit it after a month.

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/2791/finding-other-programmers-to-help-on-a-project

Comment: actually I have got the same question. would be great to get some advise on this topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A much better question to ask is "**How do I pick the right teammates/project?**"

This is an excellent article on the subject

[**How to Pick Indie Game Collaborators: 11 Things to Watch Out For**](http://www.gamecareerguide.com/features/753/how_to_pick_indie_game_.php?page=1)

> ... The first groups I joined taught me most of the items I hope to pass on to you in this article. They all had heart, and lots of dreams, but very rarely did they have sufficient talent, dedication and management. I spent easily a year and a half spinning my wheels, going from group to group, before I found a really good one...