# How do we attract more developers and other Volunteers to our Open Source MMO Emulation Project?

Tags: mmo, open-source

I am on a small development team that is tasked with completing the server side programming for an Open Source MMO project that has been in progress for about 5 years now. Approximately a year ago we Open Sourced the project hoping to draw in new developers, this was without much success and in fact we haven't gained even one active developer in our project. The Project [Star Wars Galaxies A New Hope](http://www.swganh.com), is something near and dear to myself and the other few people working on the project. It is a quest to bring back one of the golden eras in gaming, Patch 14.1 for Star Wars galaxies.

The progress as of this summer was extremely slow and it seemed as if we were taking two steps forward and one back every change we made. The codebase wasn't designed very well and we looked into completely rewriting it from scratch. After a couple of weeks we realized this couldn't be done in a timely manner and perhaps we should take another look at the old core to see if we couldn't revive it. We found it was worth just revamping the old core and continuing to push forward, we've made some really good changes that will help with the future of development. One reason we didn't really want to push heavy developer recruiting was the state of the existing codebase.

Now that it is somewhat cleaned up, how do we go about recruiting quality individuals that are interested in finishing up this Open Source MMO project and delivering what we promised to the community?

[Github Project](https://github.com/swganh)

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and say because you will eventually get a cease and desist order because you do not own the rights to create a Star Wars game?

Comment: Actually, the project is completely legal as the user has to have the original client software and we are creating everything on the backend from our own code.

Comment: A third party server most likely violates the EULA.

Comment: Duplicate of "Finding other programmers to help on a project" http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/2791/finding-other-programmers-to-help-on-a-project ?

Comment: @KyleC You have a registered trademarks by The Walt Disney Company *in the project name*.

Comment: @Philipp yeah so this post is almost 5 years old. Well before Disney bought LucasArts. In fact early on in this project we had a sort of 'blessing' from LucasArts to move forward on this project... That really doesn't matter now as the project is no longer in development.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [Finding other programmers to help on a project](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/2791/finding-other-programmers-to-help-on-a-project/2800#2800) and see if my answer there resonates.  You have already started with the code cleanup. Basically, you just need to find groups of like minded people in clumps and pitch your idea.